# usage of "very much " in reference to place

Tags: expressions

> I am very much in town.

Is this expression correct as an answer to the question whether the person is out on leave or in town?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. It strongly emphasises the speaker's urban presence, but its use is colloquial.

Comment: The use of apparent gradings to give emphasis to purely yes/no situations is common, though, as Barrie says, probably best avoided in formal settings. I once joked "Oh, you are human after all!" when meeting the boss (a rare occurrence) in the loo, and he replied "Very much so."